# Two external monitors on laptop. Recently one screen goes black (screen is still there, can't see anything) usually when starting video streaming

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've noticed this problem quite recently. I'm trying to play a game on monitor 2 and put up streaming on monitor 1 (Netflix, Crunchyroll).

Anyway, the screen just goes black. The computer hasn't lost awareness of it... It doesn't act like I unplugged it and the mouse still moves back and forth, but the screen is just black.

I'm using Windows 11 with a usb-c to HDMI connector. Already tried a different cable AND a different usbc to HDMI adaptor. If I swap HDMI cables between the actual HDMI and usbc adaptor, the monitor that goes black changes. It appears to be that whichever monitor is plugged in USB C goes dark, but only when initializing a streaming session.

I got the same behavior on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It looks like it does go black after a while, but again, only when streaming. Yesterday and today, it worked find until streaming.

Comment: It just did it when I opened a new firefox window with blank content. I am running a video encoding in the background, but otherwise, nothing of importance and nothing different compared to normal.

Comment: I fix it by briefly unplugging the HDMI then plugging it back in. It comes back immediately, but then goes out again after not too long.